# Create a sensor in STK

Tags: orbital-mechanics, stk-agi

how do I create a Sensor object which has a Rectangular 100x100 deg field of
view? Note, this is the actual field of view; Rectangular Sensors
are defined in STK by vertical and horizontal half-angles.

I want to know how to convert from actual FOV to half angles.

Comment: Can you add some information? Where exactly in STK are you entering this information? Can you add a screen shot or section number in the documentation? It's a big package and it has many versions, so also please indicate the version number. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 3):

If your field of view defined as a typical solid angle, as shown on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_view), then you'd define the half angles as the half of 100x100: 50x50.

STK (and probably other modeling tools) accounts for the visibility of a sensor using a dual-conic model similar to [an eclipsing model](https://nyxspace.com/MathSpec/celestial/eclipse/) when assuming spherical celestial objects.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm a user of STK.  @ChrisR is correct, a rectangular FOV of 100x100 would be captured in STK as a half angle sensor of 50x50.  Vertical and horizontal are referenced relative to the orientation of the sensor on the body frame (NOT relative to a horizon).